# Click event on legends of Google line/area chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to create a functionality such as :
Click on legends of line/area chart which will link to another tab; and after clicking the new tab will open.
I already achieved this functionality for bar charts i.e. clicking on each bar of google bar chart, open in new tab : [chart.getSelection() does not work properly with google bar charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35360597/chart-getselection-does-not-work-properly-with-google-bar-charts)

but i am not able to find any solution for click on legends of line chart and open in new tab.

I have gone through other question on stackoverflow. like here: [Google Line Chart Legend Click Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014010/google-line-chart-legend-click-events)
 but everywhere they mention about 'select' event on legends and using getSelection. 
But I am already using this event for select/deselect lines/areas on line/area charts. so i want to use particularly click event on the legends.

I am able to get the event through alert statement, but now i want retrieve the name of legend which is being clicked. and that is where the problem comes.
Please go through following code :

**JsFiddle Ref : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cczskgpw/2/)**

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(gChart, 'click', function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var millis = date.getTime();
            //match is undefined here, not able to retrieve name of legend which is being clicked.

            var match = e.targetID.match(/legend#\d+#/);
            console.log(match);

            if (millis - secondClick > 1000) {
                // add dealyed check if a single click occured
                setTimeout(function () {
                    // no second fast enough, it is a single click
                    if (secondClick == 0) {
                        //alert("click");
                    }
                }, 250);
            }

            // try to measure if double-clicked
            if (millis - firstClick < 250) {
                firstClick = 0;
                secondClick = millis;

                alert("doubleClick");
}
});
```

In above code, 'match' is undefined. Please help me to solve this issue.

Any help is appreciable! Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE** **SOLUTION**

```
var match = e.targetID.match(/legend/);
var rowIndex = parseInt((match['input']).substring((match['input']).lastIndexOf("#") + 1));
console.log("rowIndex :: ", rowIndex);
```

**New ISSUE**
After revised requirement, I now want to handle the click event through jQuery; any help is appreciable. Please help!

I am trying to apply click event inside ready event of google visualization.

```
var readyEvent = google.visualization.events.addListener(gChart, 'ready', function () {
            google.visualization.events.removeListener(readyEvent);

            $('.chart-container').find('#' + this.id + '').on('dblclick', function (e) {
                var xPos = e.offsetX;
                var yPos = e.offsetX;
                console.log("id :: ",this);
                var cli = gChart.getChartLayoutInterface();
                var xBounds = cli.getBoundingBox('legend');
                //var x1 = cli.getXLocation(xPos);
                console.log(" xPos, cli, xBounds, x1 :: ", xPos, cli, xBounds);
                if (
                    (xPos >= xBounds.left || xPos <= xBounds.left + xBounds.width)
                ) {
                    var snapR = Defiant.getSnapshot(data);
                    var resTot = JSON.search(snapR, '//label');
                    console.log("click event :: ", data, resTot);
                   // gChart.draw(data, options);
                }
            });
        });
```

I am making some mistake here, but not able to get. I am having many charts o single page. (chart-container is class which holds the chart-div)

Comment: @asgallant could you please help in this, i saw your answer at many questions and ultimately they helped me alot to solve my issue. But this particular issue, i am not able to solve..

Comment: does e.targetID.match(/legend#\d+#/) it really returns any thing?

Comment: it returns undefined, that is why variable 'match' is undefined. Actually I know that line is wrong, but I do not know what is correct.

Comment: In similar conditions  var match = e.targetID.match(/vAxis#\d+#label#(\d+)/); this worked for me. I tried to fit the legends in this condition. but the regular expression I am using is wrong, thats what I feel. So need correction there. or alternately please suggest any other solution to get legend text

Comment: Actually I need to detect double click event, and I found this link helpful to implement but not able to get the name of legend being clicked : Link Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503259/click-event-on-legends-of-google-line-area-chart

Comment: read this issue?https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3309

Comment: @Ajay  sorry to let you know that the link you mention about is not at all related with my problem..